# why is this pytest of simple boolean logic failing?

Tags: python, testing, pytest, boolean-logic

I don't understand why my pytest of the following function is not passing:

solutions/_and.py

```
def _and(a, b):
    if a:
        return b
    return False
```

test_and.py

```
_and_path='./solutions/'
import itertools
import sys
sys.path.append(_and_path)
print(sys.path)
import _and


def test_and():
    for i, j in itertools.product([True, False], [True, False]):
        assert(_and._and(i, j) == i and j)
```

The failure report:

```
pytest
================================================= test session starts =================================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.6.4, pytest-5.2.4, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.13.0
rootdir: C:\Users\Joseph\projects\byoc
collected 2 items

test_and.py .F                                                                                                   [100%]

====================================================== FAILURES =======================================================
______________________________________________________ test_and _______________________________________________________

    def test_and():
        for i, j in itertools.product([True, False], [True, False]):
>           assert(_and._and(i, j) == i and j)
E           assert (False == True)
E            +  where False = <function _and at 0x000001F2A5ED7BF8>(True, False)
E            +    where <function _and at 0x000001F2A5ED7BF8> = _and._and

test_and.py:14: AssertionError
============================================= 1 failed, 1 passed in 0.08s =============================================
```

I'm new to Pytest, but it seems to me that my version of `and` is returning `False` when `(True, False)` are its parameters, but `i and j` from the test is returning `True` with those same parameters.  Am I missing something?

Comment: You're testing `(_and._and(i, j) == i) and j`…

Comment: @deceze  Of course!  thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use brackets:

```
True and False == True and False # means True and (False == True) and False
Out[3]: False

(True and False) == (True and False)
Out[4]: True
```